# In angular, why do we need an extra return statement when we are trying to return some data from the custom service

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I am new to javascript and angular .

I have created a custom service in angular which connects to a url and fetches information .I am trying to return reponse.data instead if just response

```
 var getAlldatas = function($http)
    {
      var getuser= function(username){
     $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+username).then(function(response{
                 return response.data;
             });
      };
    };
```

however this isn't working until I add a return statement right before $https as show below

```
var getAlldatas = function($http)
{ var getuser= function(username){
     return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+username).then(function(response{
         return response.data;
     });

  };
};
```

please help me to understand as to why the extra "return" statement is necessary as all i need is to return response.data from this function

Comment: because the return is inside another function, the callback. returns dont cascade upward through functions. plus you are using an async function, that is a nonblocking call the js engine doesnt wait around till it finishes. hence why you use callbacks with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only ever return from the function you're in.

This means that, when you `return response.data`, you're only returning from the callback function.

By returning `$http.get`, you are also returning from your `getuser` function.

(In this example, `$http.get` returns a `promise`, so by returning `$http.get`, you're returning it's `promise`. The `promise` will contain whatever is returned from the callback, so this means you can return a `promise` containing `response.data`)

Answer (score 1):

Here `getAlldatas` & `$http.get` are to separate functions.`$http.get` is a method where `then` handles the callback function.

`return response.data;` return the response of the request but that request as not yet reached to the function which is calling `getAlldatas`. The outer `return` function is used to send that data back to the caller function. Unless the outer `return` is used , `getAlldatas` will always return undefined